# Collecting comma separated data in a single cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel table which stores results from a questionnaire. It includes a column where the responder includes multiple responses. I want to treat each response as a separate data point:

```
Favourite Colour | Age |
-------------------------
Blue, Black      | 12  |
Red, Green, Blue | 11  |
Orange           | 12  |
Black, Blue, Red | 13  |
Red, Black       | 11  |
...
```

Which would return:

```
Blue: 3
Black: 3
Red: 3
Green: 1
Orange: 1
```

Even better:

```
12 - Black: 1
   - Blue:  1
   - Orange:1
11 - Red:   2
   - Green: 1
...
```

And I would hopefully be able to put this in a graph.

I've done some reading online and come across a `LookUp` command or `LookUpV` but am not sure about them so I though I would post a question.

Hopefully I made my point clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table you give is in A1:B6 (with headers in row 1), and that you put e.g. "Blue" in D2, enter this formula in E2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($A$2:$A$6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$6,D2,"")))/LEN(D2)
```

This can then be copied down to give similar results for colours in D3, D4, etc.